# Istio Mixer container logs causing high disk space usage

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have an Istio-enabled EKS Cluster, and my nodes are constantly running out of disk space.

Calculating the overall disk usage lead me to the istio-mixer container, which has a **log file** using more than **50GB** of disk space in only **12 days** of uptime:

```
[root@ip-some-ip containers]# pwd
/var/lib/docker/containers

[root@ip-some-ip containers]# du -schx .[!.]* * | sort -h | tail -n 10
66M 8bf5e8ee5a03096c589ad8f53b9e1a3d3088ca67b0064f3796e406f00336b532
73M 657eca261461d10c5b1b81ab3078d2058b931a357395903808b0145b617c1662
101M    bb338296ff06ef42ae6177c8a88e63438c26c398a457dc3f5301ffcb4ef2682b
127M    21f2da86055ad76882730abf65d4465386bb85598f797f451e7ad66726243613
134M    9c2be24e8b9345659b6f208c9f2d4650bb1ece11e0c4b0793aa01fdfebadb44e
383M    5d5fdbe6813ddc3ff2f6eb96f62f8317bd73e24730e2f44ebc537367d9987142
419M    475f8dfc74c3df2bc95c47df56e37d1dfb9181fae9aa783dafabba8283023115
592M    9193c50e586e0c7ecaeb87cecd8be13714a5d6ccd6ea63557c034ef56b07772f
52G 9c6b3e4f26603471d0aa9b6a61b3da5a69001e6b9be34432ffa62d577738c149
54G total

[root@ip-192-168-228-194 containers]# du -hs 9c6b3e4*/*.log
52G 9c6b3e4f26603471d0aa9b6a61b3da5a69001e6b9be34432ffa62d577738c149-json.log

[root@ip-ip-some-ip containers]# docker ps -a | grep 9c6b3e4f2660
9c6b3e4f2660        d559bdcd7a88                                                       "/usr/local/bin/mi..."   12 days ago         Up 12 days                                     k8s_mixer_istio-telemetry-6b5579595f-fvm5x_istio-system_6324c262-f3b5-11e8-b615-0eccb0bb4724_0
```

**My questions are:**

- This amount of log output is expected?
- The mixer log level can be decreased? How? Changing it affects my telemetry metrics?
- There is a way to configure a log "retention period"?

**Additional info:**

- Istio v1.0.2 (deployed with the offical helm charts; no custom configs)
- k8s v1.10.11-eks
- The cluster has approximately 20 pods running in Istio-enabled namespaces

Comment: I am trying to reproduce your case and it is interesting to know, what is in this log file, and could you post its head and tail? Also, do you use any custom configurations for mixer?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev I restarted the telemetry pod to get fresh logs. [here](https://gist.github.com/eduardobaitello/6c2817ad1d1e2a73a21724efd7e4c124) is a gist file with the mixer-telemetry container logs. The first lines report _warn_ and _error_ for handlers and configs. The remaining lines are requests from my service mesh (container to container, container to rds, etc), I do not need to log all these requests, they are the problem... Istio was deployed with the official helm chart; no custom configs for mixer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem and some useful information for new Istio versions.

### Istio v1.0.2:

The huge amount of logs was being generated by the [Stdio adapter](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/adapters/stdio/):

> The stdio adapter enables Istio to output logs and metrics to the
>   local machine. Logs and metrics can be directed to Mixer’s standard
>   output stream, standard error stream, or to any locally reachable
>   file.

In Istio **v1.0.2 this adapter was enabled by default**, streaming the logs to Mixer container `stderr`. To temporarily solve this, I [deleted the following rules](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/5998#issuecomment-394181004):

```
kubectl delete rule stdio --namespace=istio-system
kubectl delete rule stdio-tcp --namespace=istio-system
```

Deleting these rules does not affect the Prometheus metrics (which are handled by [another adapter](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/adapters/prometheus/)).

### Istio v1.1.0+:

In this version, Istio introduced the `mixer.adapters.stdio.enabled` to [helm installation options](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/installation-options/#mixer-options), **disabling the stdio adapter by default**, and including the [following comment](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/2b1331886076df103179e3da5dc9077fed59c989/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/charts/mixer/values.yaml#L56):

> # stdio is a debug adapter in istio-telemetry, it is not recommended
>   for production use.

The changes were made in the following PRs:

- [Add adapter tuning install options to helm (#10525)](https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/10525)
- [Turn policy off by default (#12114)](https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/12114)

Answer (score 3):

The default value of logging level in **Mixer** is info. And the logs provided by you, confirms that you have this settings. Therefore, a lot of redundant information gathered in logs and it is possible to decrease logging level for some sources.

You can change it in two ways:

1. **On working pod without restart.**

   In your logs you can find the following line:

   ```
   2018-12-12T17:54:55.461261Z info    ControlZ available at 192.168.87.249:9876
   ```

   It means, that in the mixer container on 9876 port you can find Istio ControlZ web-interface. To get an access to it from a computer with installed `kubectl`, you need to run the following command:

   ```
   kubectl -n istio-system port-forward $(kubectl -n istio-system get pod -l istio=mixer,istio-mixer-type=telemetry -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') 9876:9876 &
   ```

   After that, in your browser go to the link http://localhost:9876/scopez/, and you will see the following dashboard, where you can change log levels:

   [image]
2. **Add `--log_output_level` flag to the `istio-telemetry` deployment for the `mixer` container.**

   Here is the description for the flag from the mixer's documentation:

   > **--log_output_level string**
   >   Comma-separated minimum per-scope logging level of messages to output, in the form of :,:,... where scope can be one of [adapters, api, attributes, default, grpcAdapter, loadshedding] and level can be one of [debug, info, warn, error, none] (default "default:info")

   Note, that for key `--log_output_level attributes:warn,api:error` in yaml file you need to use one of the following:

   - value `- --log_output_level=attributes:warn,api:error` or
   - values `- --log_output_level` and `- attributes:warn,api:error` on different lines

   The example of the deployment:

   ```
   apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
   kind: Deployment
   metadata:
     annotations:
     labels:
       chart: mixer-1.0.4
       istio: mixer
       release: istio
     name: istio-telemetry
     namespace: istio-system
   spec:
     progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
     replicas: 2
     revisionHistoryLimit: 10
     selector:
       matchLabels:
         app: telemetry
         istio: mixer
         istio-mixer-type: telemetry
     strategy:
       rollingUpdate:
         maxSurge: 1
         maxUnavailable: 1
       type: RollingUpdate
     template:
       metadata:
         annotations:
           scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ""
           sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
         creationTimestamp: null
         labels:
           app: telemetry
           istio: mixer
           istio-mixer-type: telemetry
       spec:
         containers:
         - args:                                                #Flags for the Mixer process
           - --address                                          #Flag on two different lines
           - unix:///sock/mixer.socket
           - --configStoreURL=k8s://                            #Flag with '='
           - --configDefaultNamespace=istio-system
           - --trace_zipkin_url=http://zipkin:9411/api/v1/spans
           - --log_output_level=attributes:warn,api:error       # <------ THIS LINE IS WHAT YOU ARE LOOKING FOR
           env:
           - name: GODEBUG
             value: gctrace=2
           image: docker.io/istio/mixer:1.0.4
           imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
           livenessProbe:
             failureThreshold: 3
             httpGet:
               path: /version
               port: 9093
               scheme: HTTP
             initialDelaySeconds: 5
             periodSeconds: 5
             successThreshold: 1
             timeoutSeconds: 1
           name: mixer
           ports:
           - containerPort: 9093
             protocol: TCP
           - containerPort: 42422
             protocol: TCP
           resources:
             requests:
               cpu: 10m
           terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
           terminationMessagePolicy: File
           volumeMounts:
           - mountPath: /sock
             name: uds-socket
         - args:
           - proxy
           - --serviceCluster
           - istio-telemetry
           - --templateFile
           - /etc/istio/proxy/envoy_telemetry.yaml.tmpl
           - --controlPlaneAuthPolicy
           - MUTUAL_TLS
           env:
           - name: POD_NAME
             valueFrom:
               fieldRef:
                 apiVersion: v1
                 fieldPath: metadata.name
           - name: POD_NAMESPACE
             valueFrom:
               fieldRef:
                 apiVersion: v1
                 fieldPath: metadata.namespace
           - name: INSTANCE_IP
             valueFrom:
               fieldRef:
                 apiVersion: v1
                 fieldPath: status.podIP
           image: docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.0.4
           imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
           name: istio-proxy
           ports:
           - containerPort: 15090
             name: http-envoy-prom
             protocol: TCP
           resources:
             requests:
               cpu: 10m
           terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
           terminationMessagePolicy: File
           volumeMounts:
           - mountPath: /etc/certs
             name: istio-certs
             readOnly: true
           - mountPath: /sock
             name: uds-socket
         dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
         restartPolicy: Always
         schedulerName: default-scheduler
         securityContext: {}
         serviceAccount: istio-mixer-service-account
         serviceAccountName: istio-mixer-service-account
         terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
         volumes:
         - name: istio-certs
           secret:
             defaultMode: 420
             optional: true
             secretName: istio.istio-mixer-service-account
         - emptyDir: {}
           name: uds-socket
   ```

**Additionally, you can configure log rotation for mixer process using the following flags:**

> --log_rotate string                   The path for the optional rotating log file
>
> --log_rotate_max_age int              The maximum age in days of a log file beyond which the file is rotated (0 indicates no limit) (default 30)
>
> --log_rotate_max_backups int          The maximum number of log file backups to keep before older files are deleted (0 indicates no limit) (default 1000)
>
> --log_rotate_max_size int             The maximum size in megabytes of a log file beyond which the file is rotated (default 104857600)

However, I have no possibility to generate a huge amount of such logs and test how it works.

**Links:**

Unfortunately, the [official documentation](https://istio.io/help/ops/component-logging/) is not good, but maybe it helps somehow.

And as a bonus, [here](https://istio.io/docs/reference/commands/mixs/#mixs-server) is the list of all mixer server flags.

Comment: thanks for all the detailed info! I'll give it a try soon. I have a **question**: If I decrease the Mixer `--log_output_level`, the metrics sent to Prometheus will be affected? i.e., The Istio Grafana Dashboards will lack information.

Comment: I think no, because it is about logs of mixer application. But of course, you need to check it to be sure.

Comment: Artem, I finally managed it to work...Unfortunately, your recommendations did not work but lead me to [this](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/5998) issue. The logs were being generated by `adapters`, which cannot be controlled by the `mix serv` flags. Deleting `stdio` and `stdiotcp` rules solved my problem. Many thanks for your help! Do you mind if I write up and accept an answer with the steps to solve it?

Comment: You should, I think :)